# How to change highlight color of selected NavigationLink?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, mac-catalyst

I got master/detail view app where UI is build with SwiftUI.

Master view is a `List` of `NavigationLink`'s. Data for each `NavigationLink` is populated via Core Data fetch request.

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct FilteredList: View {
    var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Book>
    var books: FetchedResults<Book> {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(books, id: \.self) { book in
                NavigationLink(destination: BookDetailView(book: book)) {
                    HStack {
                        Text(book ?? "Book Default Title")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve: I need to change background of currently selected `NavigationLink` in `List` to say, for example, system green color. Please, see the screenshot:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.